# Unable to return a filtered array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, higher-order-functions

## Overview

I am new to the Swift language, but not others, and am having trouble executing a simple `Array.filter` statement that I would like to return as the result for a function in a class I am writing, but it seems adding the `return` keywords causes non-intuitive compile errors.

**Question:** Does anyone know what to make of these error messages, and how to fix them?

## Samples

### Declarations

```
var arrDictIVar = [["dictVar1": "value"]]
...
func someFunc(var1: String) {...
```

### Various Trials

#### Set 1

```
return arrDictIVar.filter({
  $0["dictVar1"] == var1
}) 

return arrDictIVar.filter(){
  $0["dictVar1"] == var1
}

return arrDictIVar.filter{
  $0["dictVar1"] == var1
}
```

**Error:** `Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(@noescape ([String : String]) throws -> Bool)'`
**Error Subtext:** `Expected an argument list of type '(@noescape (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool)'`

Source: [Sample MCVE](http://swiftstub.com/399462580) [Execute here](http://www.runswiftlang.com/)

#### Set 2

```
return arrDictIVar.filter({
  $0["dictVar1"] == var1
})[0]

return arrDictIVar.filter() {
  $0["dictVar1"] == var1
}[0]

return arrDictIVar.filter{
  $0["dictVar1"] == var1
}[0]
```

**Error:** `Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : String]]'`

Source: [Sample MCVE](http://swiftstub.com/133382929) [Execute here](http://www.runswiftlang.com/)

#### Set 3

```
arrDictIVar.filter({
   $0["dictVar1"] == var1
})

arrDictIVar.filter(){
   $0["dictVar1"] == var1
}

arrDictIVar.filter{
   $0["dictVar1"] == var1
}
```

**Warning:** `Result of call to 'filter' is unused`
**Note:** Just to show that the block is properly formed without the `return` keyword.

Source: [Sample MCVE](http://swiftstub.com/600223626) ([Execute here](http://www.runswiftlang.com/))

### Other Information

I have also tried modifying the IVar declaration to `var arrDictIVar: Array<Dictionary<String,String>> = [...`, and the function declaration to `func someFunc(var1: String) -> Dictionary<String,String>{...` at various times, with similar failures.

**Edit:** I had posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36021932/1091943) at the same time of this question as I found a combination that worked towards nearing the end of this posting.  It does include changing the return data type in the method signature, along with giving other information alluding to the inaccurate, or at least confusing nature, of the compiler, and the error messages it presents.

After this I was left with a follow-up question:

> If anyone would be able to explain why this was happening, and give a clear judgement as the compiler error message was not as helpful as it could be, my reading/interpretation of the error message was not as clear as it could have been, potentially saving time by changing my mindset somehow, or either, please comment on that note.

[Victor Sigler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36023478/1091943) does seem to cover this in some good detail.

Comment: It looks as if `func someFunc(var1: String) {` has no explicit return type, in so inferring return type to be `()` (`Void`/ empty tuple). In that context, it makes no sense to attempt to return the result of an `filter` operation on an array of dictionaries, as this will be an array (possibly empty) of dictionaries itself. Consider showing us a [minimal, complete and _verifiable_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, instead of several snippets on their own.

Comment: @Pysis See my answer to clarify your doubts

Comment: @dfri That comment is more representative of an answer, and I had already pasted my thoughts in my own.
For the MCVE, I have intentionally shown the "Declarations" and "Various Trials" sections so that they may be paired together to create sample MCVEs, and show the different syntactical combinations I have tried, also showing what code directly leads to the various error messages.

Comment: I have since added some links if anybody also needs to see more 'complete' code examples.

Comment: @Pysis I won't belittle your effort here, but for a true MVCE (which makes it as easy as possibly for us possible answerers to help you), include it in such a form that we can use it directly to reproduce your problem, withiut needing to patch parts together. Your edit above does now include a link to such an example, but consider next time to just start with the MVCE (not linked to, but pasted in code block). Thereafter, include details and investigations on your own, if applicable. ... <cont'd>

Comment: ... Note also that I didn't downvote this question (and don't think it should be downvoted), I'm simply giving you feedback on how you can present your question in a manner that will make it more probable that people will dig into and attempt to answer it. (Since so many questions are posted each day here at SO, generally answerers tend to choose to put effort into those that are truly easy to reproduce, in so getting straight to finding out and explaining what the issue might be: sometimes too many details can scare answerers off as too much content might obscure what the actual question is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's explain in detail every set you have put in your question:

> **Set 1:**

Your three examples are right in code and are the same to the compiler, you're using a trailing closure and the parentheses can be omitted.

Sometimes the compiler(because it's so young yet!!!) not show the exactly error happening in your code, but definitely in this step you're using the `filter` function to return an `[[String: String]]` or an array of dictionaries and you're missing the type of the return of the function, it's assumed by the compiler as `Void`.

**About `@noescape`:**

Adding `@noescape` guarantees that the closure will not be stored somewhere, used at a later time, or used asynchronously. Remember that closures capture values.

You can read more about the `@noescape` clause in the following two very good tutorials:

- [@noescape Attribute](http://nshint.io/blog/2015/10/23/noescape-attribute/)
- [Hipster Swift: Demystifying the Mysterious — KrakenDev](http://krakendev.io/blog/hipster-swift)

So to resume it, if you change your function to the following it should work:

```
func someFunc(var1: String) -> [[String: String]] {
   return arrDictIVar.filter({
      $0["dictVar1"] == var1
   })
}
```

> **Set 2:**

If you fix the error in the **Set 1** then when you code:

```
return arrDictIVar.filter{
   $0["dictVar1"] == var1
}[0]
```

You're trying to return a `[String: String]` or a dictionary and it's wrong regarding the return type of the function it's `[[String: String]]`.

But be careful because if you change the return type to `[String: String]` and try to index the array returned for the `filter` function and there is nothing founded by the `filter` function you would get an runtime error.

> **Set 3**

I think it is the more easy to understand because as the warning said, the `filter` function returns a new list of elements and if you don't save it or returned in your function it's unused, something like this:

```
func someFunc(var1: String){
   arrDictIVar.filter({
      $0["dictVar1"] == var1
   })
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: This answer does give some detailed information about the error message and solution, also for each set, although I only provided each as examples to show the different parsing error message the compiler displays to attempt to better understand the one problem.
I invite people to my answer only to highlight the additional information concerning the debugging technique and underlying relationship the compiler seems to have.

Comment: @Pysis My answer solve your problem, I'm sorry to say this but stackoverflow is not a debate forum, in fact if your question was too broad can be closed. Please if my question solves your problem accept it to can be helpful for someone else.

Comment: Ah, yes, I only meant to clarify that I think your answer covers some areas, and mine does a few others.